# Share Angular2 Service across multiple windows

Tags: angularjs, angular, browser, typescript

My website is built with Angular2. Imagine it as a big dashboard with a lot of modules. Sometimes information from multiple modules are required at the same time - therefore I want to allow my users to open a module in a new window. A real-world example for this is the video container of Hangout.

From my research there would be 2 ways to do this:

1. I open the route of the selected Ng-Component in a new window. As a result angular would reinit all services. To keep my data consistent I would need find a way to sync the instances. Maybe some kind of service that writes all attributes to localStorage?
2. This is somehow the way GoldenLayout implemented the [Popouts](https://www.golden-layout.com/tutorials/working-with-popouts.html).
   I could init my component in window A and hide it - Now open a new window (B) and pass a copy (Css, HTML, Data) of my component to it. This would mean that I only need to sync the mirrored component, but I am not sure if this is good architecture.

Which way would you go to solve the described problem and are there more elegant solutions?

Comment: Sure, data should be synced through localStorage. Consider ngrx, it may be particularly useful for saving states.

Comment: Hi estus, thanks for the tip. I checked ngrx, looks promising, but still synchronization would go throught the localStorage. I would rather prefer a solution where I don't have to bootstrap the whole app again. I took a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/SharedWorker, it sounds very neat. However, I didn't figure out yet how to use it for my ng2-services. Will tell you when I found a solution.

Comment: Yes, synchronization goes through localStorage (or sessionStorage, depending on the case). Model service or ngrx store can make this totally transparent. Shared workers aren't good for compatibility, this depends on the case also.

Comment: If localStorage is what you're going for, you should check the redux design pattern